# ATI Graphics - version doubt

Tags: ati

currently i'm using ubuntu 12.04 (wich is a blast!!!) and i've been working around with the graphics and testing several programs like skype, VLC and others with video.. I've noticed that there is a bug that doesn't allow to run skype has it should. Currently i've noticed that if i disable accelaration video on VLC all works fine...
I've noticed also that if i disable proprietary graphics all things works very well too. I think it might be a video accelaration bug. 
So, i want to know wich ati Radeon version am i using right now. There's some command that i can put in terminal and see that?

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find your graphics driver version in file /var/log/Xorg.0.log. There will be multiple occurrences, but search for string "LoadModule". When you get to the one with your display adapter name in it, e.g., fglrx for the ATI proprietary driver, the next few lines should show your driver version.

For example, my system has:

```
[    15.540] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[    15.540] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/extra-modules.dpkg-tmp/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
[    15.549] (II) Module fglrx: vendor="FireGL - ATI Technologies Inc."
[    15.549]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 8.95.3
```